# creating a dictionary with words as keys and their count in document as value for texts in data frame

Tags: python, text-mining

I am trying to build a function which takes a column in dataframe and returns a data frame with words and their count

```
def word_count(dataframe):
    masterlist=[]
    masterset={}
    for ask in masterlist:
        masterset[ask]=0
    
    corpus_length=len(dataframe)
    for i in range(0,corpus_length):
        cleaned_sentence=sentence_cleaner(dataframe[i])
        tweetlength=len(cleaned_sentence)
        for j in range(0,len(cleaned_sentence)):
            w=dataframe[i][j]
            if w in masterset:
                masterset[w]=masterset[w]+1
            if w not in masterset:
                masterlist.append(w)
                
                masterset[w]=1
    print('completed')
    word_countdataframe=pd.DataFrame(masterset)
    return(word_countdataframe)
```

Comment: What is your requirement?Or expected output vs obtained output

Comment: Please look into pandas value_counts() and other options instead of using loops. There are much easier ways to get this done. You can also use apply if you want to iterate through each row

Comment: For minimal code reproducible you should also provide 1) function sentence_cleaner and 2) short data example

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do something like this?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'word':['cat','dog','fish','cat','fish']})
df.word.value_counts()
```

returns:

```
cat     2
fish    2
dog     1
Name: word, dtype: int64
```